# Combining Players to Form Unique Teams

Tags: combinatorics

I need to setup teams for a curling league

There are 24 curlers

```
6 are skips  1 to 6
6 are vice   7 to 12
6 are seconds 13 to 18
6 are leads  19 to 24
```

I need a 6 game schedule of teams, where no two people ever play on the same team

```
game 1  skip 1 and vice 7
game 2  skip 1 and vice 8
game 3  skip 1 and vice 9
game 4  skip 1 and vice 10
game 5  skip 1 and vice 11
game 6  skip 1 and vice 12
```

I need to complete the above for all 4 players on a team and not get duplicate
I have worked on this for many hours, but can never seem to eliminate duplicates

i.e. curler 10 plays with curler 24 two of the 6 games for example

Hope you can help me -- and thanks in advance

Comment: *"I need a 6 game schedule of teams, where no two people ever play on the same team"* That is not clear. Which two people ? Obviously there are always two people who play on the same team. For instance, skip 1 and vice 7.

Comment: If it's only $6$ games, does that mean skips $2$ to $6$ never play?

Comment: all 6 teams play each game or draw

Comment: i.e 1 vs 6 2 vs 5 3 vs 4  then

Comment: 1 vs 2  3 vs 4  5 vs 6   etc